# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln(\ln(n))}\right)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Study the convergence of the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln(\ln(n))}\right)}}$$

The absolute convergence is giving me hard times, eventually I was following this path, any tips?

$\left( n^{\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln(\ln(n))}\right)}\right)^{-1} = \left( e^{\ln(n)+\frac{1}{\ln(\ln(n))}\ln(n)}\right)^{-1} = \left( e^{\ln(n)\left(1+\frac{1}{\ln(\ln(n))}\right)}\right)^{-1} =\,\,\,\,$?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{\ln{n}}{\ln{\ln{n}}} \geq 2\ln{\ln{n}}$ when $n$ is large.

Comment: @Mindlack how to show that fact? Thank you

Comment: If $x \geq C >0$, $x \geq 2(\ln{x})^2$. So if $n \geq e^C$, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$\dfrac{x}{\ln(x)}
\to \infty
$
as
$x \to \infty$,
it follows that
$\dfrac{f(x)}{f(\ln(x))}
\to \infty
$
as
$x \to \infty$
where $f$ is any positive,
strictly increasing,
continuous,
unbounded function.

Take
$f(x) = \ln(x)$
to get the desired result.